# ASP.Net URL rewriting and authentication

Tags: .net, asp.net, authentication, url-rewriting

I have a web application using the .Net 2.0 framework. The whole website is restricted to authenticated users using Windows authentication. These rules are set in the web.config file the following way :

```
<location path="/">
    <system.web>
        <authorization>
            <allow roles="CustomerAdministrator, Manager"/>
            <deny users="*"/>
        </authorization>
    </system.web>
</location>
<location path="Path/To/Public/File.aspx">
    <system.web>
        <authorization>
            <allow users="*"/>
        </authorization>
    </system.web>
</location>
[...]
```

As shown above, I have one page that I want to be public. Up to this point, everything works fine. We recently added url rewriting for nicer urls, so I set a rewrite rule for the public page :

```
<RewriterConfig>
    <Rules>
        <RewriterRule>
            <LookFor>~/Public</LookFor>
            <SendTo><![CDATA[~/Path/To/Public/File.aspx]]></SendTo>
        </RewriterRule>
    </Rules>
</RewriterConfig>
```

Now, when accessing the public page by its direct url, it works as expected (no authentication required), but when I try to access the page through its rewrited url, it asks for authentication.

Does anyone know where this problem my come from ?

Comment: What are you using to re-write the URLs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually found the problem. I am using an `URLRewriter` project some of my colleague found on the web, and the problem came from the fact that it was registering itself at the `HttpApplication`'s `AuthorizeRequest` event. While this works with Forms authentication, it doesn't with Windows authentication, which I'm using.

To solve the problem, I simply had to change it such that it registers to the `BeginRequest` event instead (as written in the comments... RTFM...).

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried changing your location tag to use the /Public URL?